# How to ping router from L3 switch

Tags: routing, switch, ping, network-access, route

I am stuck in that that switch can't ping router and router can't ping switch. 
How to fix that ?

I tried so much variants but them didn't help me

Actually router must do static routing, that i am trying to do but that doesn't help me

I know that some config is awful here, actually on that connected switch but I am learning.
Picture

[image]

**L3 switch show run code**

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 12
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-11
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 4
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 5
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 6
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 7
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 8
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport access vlan 9
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 11
 switchport mode access
 switchport nonegotiate
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan2
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e01
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan3
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e02
 ip address 192.168.0.9 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan4
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e03
 ip address 192.168.0.17 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan5
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e04
 ip address 192.168.0.25 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan6
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e05
 ip address 192.168.0.33 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan7
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e06
 ip address 192.168.0.41 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan8
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e07
 ip address 192.168.0.49 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan9
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e08
 ip address 192.168.0.57 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e09
 ip address 192.168.0.65 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan11
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e0a
 ip address 192.168.0.73 255.255.255.248
!
interface Vlan12
 mac-address 000a.41cd.4e0b
 ip address 192.168.0.82 255.255.255.248
!
router rip
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.0
```

**Router show run code**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 196.168.0.81 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
!
ip classless
```

**Router show ip route**

```
 Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
           D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
           N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
           E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
           i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
           * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
           P - periodic downloaded static route

    Gateway of last resort is not set

         196.168.0.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
    C       196.168.0.80/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
    L       196.168.0.81/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
```

Comment: please provide screen shot of your diagram. You can insert it here.

Comment: If you have doubt about your code which you configured, code sample also

Comment: @infra, done. code sample provided and picture also too

Comment: You've got two routers and three L3 switches in your diagram. Which ones can't ping each other and where are the links in between? Which ports connect to each other?

Comment: @Zac67, Second router is redundant , i have tested one thing. that router what is connected need to be configured

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: - Check L1, is there a physical connection? - Check L2, is there a common VLan, both devices conencted to it? - Check L3, are bothe devices in the same IP network?

Comment: Sadly school assignments are off topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to connect switch interface FastEthernet0/1 to the router interface GigabitEthernet0/1 is that right?

If you want to route traffic from vlan 2-11 to the router you must:

- delete interface Vlan12
- configure the IP directly on the interface FastEthernet0/1

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.0.82 255.255.255.248

Now it should be possible to ping the switch from the router or vice versa

Comment: It is impossible to configure IP on any interface on L3 switch without Vlan

Comment: @AwesomeMan, you clearly don't know how to configure an IP without a vlan, but it's quite simple (assuming the switch supports it).  Go into interface config mode, type `no switchport`, and then configure your IP address

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure router-on-a-stick.

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-11
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate

Router(config)# interface g0/0.20
Router(config-subif)# encapsulation dot1q 20
Router(config-subif)# ip add x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
Router(config-subif)# interface g0/0.30
Router(config-subif)# encapsulation dot1q 30
Router(config-subif)# ip add x.x.x.y x.x.x.x
....(add remanining vlan 4,5,6...)
Router(config)# interface g0/0
Router(config-if)# no shut
```